# how to exec a command when receive "200 ok" from b-leg in asterisk dialplan?

Tags: asterisk

In Asterisk v13.38.3, I want to exec a command when receive "200 ok" from b-leg in dialplan, I try to use `Dial(,,M)`, this:

```
same => n,Dial(SIP/...,,M(BLeg-Answer^${ARG}))
```

but `BLeg-Answer` exec before receiving "200 ok", how to exec the command just when receive "200 ok" from b-leg?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Asterisk is PBX.

Closest event for that is "channel state changed to answered"(collectable via AMI events). Yes, it is per-channel so can be collected for "leg"

You can't monitor every sip packet, for that use Kamailio or Opensips.